# HTML won't display image (image is stored locally and in the same directory with html file)

Tags: html

The webpage won't display my image and shows the broken image icon, image is in the same directory as index.html in the folder called web-dev, here's the code:

```
<img src=”image1.jpg”  height = "100" width = "100">
```

[image]

Comment: first double quotes look different than the others.

Comment: Thank you very much I cannot believe I didn't see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `"` instead of `”`.

Like this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg"  height = "100" width = "100">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<img src="images1.jpg" alt="images1" width="100" height="100" />
```